# Changing config and loading Hugging Face model fine-tuned on a downstream task

Tags: python, pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I am using HuggingFace models for `TokenClassification` task. I have the following label2id mapping. I am using version 3.3.0 of the library

```
label2id = {
    "B-ADD": 4,
    "B-ARRESTED": 7,
    "B-CRIME": 2,
    "B-INCIDENT_DATE": 3,
    "B-SUSPECT": 9,
    "B-VICTIMS": 1,
    "B-WPN": 5,
    "I-ADD": 8,
    "I-ARRESTED": 13,
    "I-CRIME": 11,
    "I-INCIDENT_DATE": 10,
    "I-SUSPECT": 14,
    "I-VICTIMS": 12,
    "I-WPN": 6,
    "O": 0
  }
```

The following scenario works well and the model gets loaded correctly.

```
from transformers import AutoModelForTokenClassification, AutoTokenizer, AutoConfig

pretrained_model_name = "bert-base-cased"
config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name)

id2label = {y:x for x,y in label2id.items()}
config.label2id = label2id
config.id2label = id2label
config._num_labels = len(label2id)

model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name, config=config)

model
```

I get the following output. The last layer have been correctly initialized with 15 neurons (numer of token category to predict).

```
.....................
      (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
      (classifier): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=15, bias=True)
    )
```

but if I changed the `pretrained_model_name` to `"dbmdz/bert-large-cased-finetuned-conll03-english"`, I am getting the following error

```
loading weights file https://cdn.huggingface.co/dbmdz/bert-large-cased-finetuned-conll03-english/pytorch_model.bin from cache at C:\Users\anu10961/.cache\torch\transformers\4b02c1fe04cf7f7e6972536150e9fb329c7b3d5720b82afdac509bd750c705d2.6dcb154688bb97608a563afbf68ba07ae6f7beafd9bd98b5a043cd269fcc02b4
All model checkpoint weights were used when initializing BertForTokenClassification.

All the weights of BertForTokenClassification were initialized from the model checkpoint at dbmdz/bert-large-cased-finetuned-conll03-english.
If your task is similar to the task the model of the checkpoint was trained on, you can already use BertForTokenClassification for predictions without further training.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-2969a8092bf4> in <module>
----> 1 model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name, config=config)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\arcgis183\lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_auto.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, **kwargs)
   1372         if type(config) in MODEL_FOR_TOKEN_CLASSIFICATION_MAPPING.keys():
   1373             return MODEL_FOR_TOKEN_CLASSIFICATION_MAPPING[type(config)].from_pretrained(
-> 1374                 pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, config=config, **kwargs
   1375             )
   1376 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\arcgis183\lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_utils.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, **kwargs)
   1047                 raise RuntimeError(
   1048                     "Error(s) in loading state_dict for {}:\n\t{}".format(
-> 1049                         model.__class__.__name__, "\n\t".join(error_msgs)
   1050                     )
   1051                 )

RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for BertForTokenClassification:
    size mismatch for classifier.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([9, 1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([15, 1024]).
    size mismatch for classifier.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([9]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([15]).
```

The only difference I could see is the model `dbmdz/bert-large-cased-finetuned-conll03-english` is already finetuned on `TokenClassification` task and it model config has these `label2id` mappings

```
label2id = {
    "B-LOC": 7,
    "B-MISC": 1,
    "B-ORG": 5,
    "B-PER": 3,
    "I-LOC": 8,
    "I-MISC": 2,
    "I-ORG": 6,
    "I-PER": 4,
    "O": 0
  }
```

But still I feel that we can change the last layer of this model and use it for my specific task (although I need to train the model first before using it for inferencing)

Answer (score 4):

Once a part of the model is in the saved pre-trained model, you cannot change its hyperparameters. By setting the pre-trained model and the config, you are saying that you want a model that classifies into 15 classes and that you want to initialize with a model that uses 9 classes and that does not work.

If I understand correctly you want to initialize the underlying BERT from a different classifier. A workaround that can do it is:

1. Load only the underlying BERT without the classification layer;
2. Initialize a classification model from scratch;
3. Replace the randomly initialized BERT in the new classifier with the pre-trained one.

```py
from Transformers import AutoModel, AutoModelForTokenClassification
bert = AutoModel.from_pretrained('dbmdz/bert-large-cased-finetuned-conll03-english')
classifier = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_config(config)
classifier.bert = bert
```

Comment: I guess 3rd line should be classifier = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_config(config)

Comment: I didn't asked this on my original question, but what if I would like to make the above code generic enough so that it can work with any fine tuned model (no matter if the architecture is BERT, RoBERTa, XLNet, etc)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem that you faced can be solved by passing this argument `ignore_mismatched_sizes=True` like below

```
model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name, config=config, ignore_mismatched_sizes=True)
```

more information can be found [here](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/how-do-i-change-the-classification-head-of-a-model/4720/1) and [here](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/how-do-i-change-the-classification-head-of-a-model/4720/19?u=abdullahalzubaer)

I also checked your code in colab and had a similar issue and then when I added `ignore_mismatched_sizes=True`, it solved the issue I think. Also, the `RuntimeError` message has included a new line (which I believe was no available before)

```
You may consider adding `ignore_mismatched_sizes=True` in the model `from_pretrained` method.
```

I hope it solves the issue to a certain degree, but I am quite new to transformers and still exploring this library.

Thanks :)